# Basic regexp help

Tags: php, regex

I am new to programming PHP and am trying to validate a field in a form.

The field if for a RAL color code and so would look something like : `RAL 1001`.
so the letters RAL and then 4 numbers.

Can someone help me set them into a regular expression to validate them.
i have tried this with no success:

```
$string_exp = "/^[RAL][0-9 .-]+$/i";
```

What can I say but sorry for being a complete NOOB at PHP.

Cheers
Ben

Comment: `[RAL]` means one of these letters: if you meant the string "RAL", get rid of the square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[RAL]` will match just one character, either R, A or L, whereas you want to match the string "RAL". So you probably want something like this,

```
$string_exp = "/^RAL[0-9]{4}$/";
```

This will match `"RAL1001"`, but not `"RAL1"`,`"RAL 1001"`, `"RAL12345"`, etc. If you wanted the space between RAL and the number, then also put that space into the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

By removing redundant character classes, you'd get:

```
/^RAL \d{4}$/i
```

Note that using case-insensitive flag would make it match even such cases as `Ral 1245` or `raL 9875`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^RAL [0-9]{4}$/
```

If you enter letters as they are, they are found as they are. If you enclose something in `[]`, it means: "Search a single character that is one of these."

Therefore starting with a literal "RAL " finds a literal "RAL " (or "ral ", too, when you apply the `i` flag).

Answer (score 0):

Depends!

```
...
if( preg_match('/RAL\s*(\d{4})(?!\d)/', $name, $m) ) {
   echo $m[1];
}
...
```

This accepts 'someRAL 1234within text'
but doesn't accept 'RAL 12345'.

The exact regex depends entirely on your
context or specifications. You have to be
more explicit in your question.

Comment: "The field if for a RAL color code and so would look something like : RAL 1001. so the letters RAL and then 4 numbers."

I thought this was pretty explicit.

Comment: casben79, the formal problem is relatively simple, just /RAL\d{4}/. My question would be, *what else*? In what form does the data show up? Which of the following would be allowed or not?
'RAL1234', 'RAL . 1234', 'RAL . . 1234', 'xxxRAL1234yyy' and so on.